# Can not Find module in "index.js"

Tags: node.js, express

**I'm stuck in this error...I'm trying but I can not fix it**
**This is my index.js file**

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
const connect = async () => {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
      console.log("Connected to mongoDB.");
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
  mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected!");
  });

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    connect();
    console.log("Connected to backend.");
  });
```

**This is my pacakge.json file**

```
{
  "name": "quiz-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

**when I run this app it shows this error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YpGx.png)

Comment: It cant find the file you're looking for. Use `dir` in cmd in the folder and share the output

Comment: What is you CWD?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node MODULE\_NOT\_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083351/node-module-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **ES6** style importing `import express from "express";` but your *package.json* doesn't know about that. Because the default is **CommonJS** for Node.js right now. And that means it wants you to use `const express = require("express");`

If you want to change that to ES6, you need to add `"type": "module",` in your package.json.

For example:

```
  ...
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  ...
```

Comment: I followed this method but it is not working

Comment: What about your folder structure? Is your index.js file and package.json file in the same directory? Because you need to give exact path of index.js in package.json.

Comment: yes, the index.js file and package.json file in the same directory

Comment: Okay, it can be node installation or version problem. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51015627/11586487