# How to upgrade angular-cli on Linux? Node.js V6.14.3 not supported by CLI v6

Tags: node.js, linux, angular-cli

Whenever I enter `ng` in termial, it outputs

> You are running version v6.14.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by
>   Angular CLI v6. The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9
>   and greater.
>
> Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to
>   update Node.js

How to fix this issue?

This happens only in non root user account, works fine with root account

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js Try this firtst

Comment: _This happens only in non root user account, works fine with root account_ Two versions of node installed, one for sudo one for no su...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates, that your node version is not supported by angular. 
So you should rather update node. 
The current LTS is 8.11.3 which you can download here:

https://nodejs.org/en/

I've been using 'nvm' for this, it is a node version manager that allows you to install and switch between node versions very easily.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It works fine wit root account, This error only comes in non root user account

Answer (score 1):

I was using nodejs v4.2.6 and npm v3.10.10
When I ran npm install -g @angular/cli, I think it tried to install latest version of angular-cli, hence I was getting this error.

> You are running version v6.14.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6. The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.

Due to some reason, I didn't wanted to upgrade to latest node and npm packages, so I resolved it by `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Use n module from npm in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use:
`sudo n latest`

To undo:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy # fix /usr/bin/node
sudo n rm 6.0.0 # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n
```

Found in [David Walsh blog](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)