# How I can update nodejs and npm version?

Tags: node.js, npm

I install nodejs and npm.

but now I want to update to the latest version, i tried many ways but it didn’t work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**For Node.js Upgrade:**

**Linux/Mac:**

The module n makes version-management easy:

```
sudo npm install n -g
```

For the latest stable version:

```
sudo n stable
```

For the latest version:

```
sudo n latest
```

**Windows:**

Just reinstall node from the .msi in Windows from the node website.

**For NPM Upgrade:**

Kindly go through [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm) for windows update.

**For Linux/Mac:**

You can upgrade to the latest version of npm using:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Or upgrade to the most recent release:

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

Answer (score 1):

managing node versions is easy with [nvmfor linux](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

the docs for how to install them are available at their respective github repos.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to install the nvm first.

Nvm is a script-based node version manager. You can install it easily with a curl and bash one-liner as described in the https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. It's also available on Homebrew.

2. Assuming you have successfully installed nvm. The following will install the latest version of the node.

```
$ nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

Answer (score 0):

The better answer here is focus into the last LTS version, but if you need a specific version, you can do:

Install NVM: Follow the instructions https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating !

Install Your Desired Version: Run nvm install **version**

Switch to the New Version: Use nvm use **version**

**version** = v18.18.2 for exemple.

I follow this article https://mcengkuru.medium.com/how-to-update-node-js-to-any-version-a-step-by-step-guide-d4ce747ac50f !