# nyc + mocha + es6 modules

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nyc

I am trying to use nyc + mocha to get test coverage on my unit tests that uses the es6 module syntax.
When I run `mocha my_test.mjs` everything works fine. The dependencies within my_test.mjs (using native import) are resolved correctly.
But when I prepend this command with nyc: `nyc mocha my_test.mjs` it doesn't work anymore, throwing this error:

```
node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:6
    return import(url.pathToFileURL(file));
           ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.replacementCompile (nodejs/core/tests/cache.install.nodejs_install/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:60:13)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

I tried different variants `nyc --require esm mocha my_test.mjs` or forcing `--experimental-modules` with node but nothing seems to work.

Note, I am using the latest version of node, nyc and mocha

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried updating to Node 14?

Comment: I am using 14.4.0

Answer (score 7):

For anybody who finds this by searching, the [c8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8) code coverage tool was a drop in replacement for me.
I literally just installed it and replaced 'nyc' with 'c8' in my package.json scripts.

Also, here is the open (at the time I wrote this) nyc issue if you are curious: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/659

Comment: Thank you Dave that worked for me! The guy behind that project is totally underated! Benjamin, in case you read this one day - you are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue after updating my dependencies. I updated to mocha version 8.x, while still using mocha.opts for configuration.

> #4175: Having been deprecated with a warning since v7.0.0, mocha.opts is no longer supported

See the release notes: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/releases/tag/v8.0.0

Reverting back to mocha 7.x helped me in the end*.
If you don't want to use mocha 7 or older, you can replace mocha.opts with a configuration file:
https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs

*note: On the way, I also added

```
"@types/node": "14.0.14",
"@types/mocha": "7.0.2",
```

to package.json. My nyc version is `"nyc": "15.1.0",` But I am not sure if that is necessary to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of seeming patronising; I noticed above you said you were on 14.4.0 do double check your version.  I thought I was on 14.x because I had updated my package.json and when I typed:

```
npm list | grep node
```

I got:

```
+-- @types/node@14.0.26
+-- nodemon@2.0.4
+-- ts-node@8.10.2
```

I'm newby to Node enough to get tripped up.  If I typed:

```
node --version
```

Then I found I was on a much older one.

Once I updated to the latest version (14.6.0) this error went away.  I'm using Windows so had to download the latest from nodejs.org.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have an old nodejs version, follow link below to upgrade your node version:
Had same issue and am fine now!

[How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem with you。Actually，I revise this file 
**node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js** 
from

```
return import(url.pathToFileURL(file));
```

to

```
return require(url.pathToFileURL(file));
```

it can works.

Comment: I don't think that changing node_modules/mocha (or any file in node_modules directly) is a good practice.