# node js discord bot is not works

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
    /home/discord/project/bloodmoon/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:42
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/discord/project/bloodmoon/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

i'm interested in developing discord bot. so i tried it. first, it works.
but, i moved the server and i setted it. and it not works! please give advise to me.

(please understand i can't write a English essay well. sorry)

Comment: Can you share your **code** please? This looks like a **sytax error** and we won't be able to help with only the error message :D

Comment: it is not a sytax error!
" first, it works. but, i moved the server and i setted it. and it not works!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [discord.js source code](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/Client.js#L42), you can see that they're trying to silently ignore if there is an error when their code requires the `worker_threads` module. They simply omit the usual `(error)` part after `catch`:

```js
try {
  // Test if worker threads module is present and used
  data = require('worker_threads').workerData || data;
} catch {
  // Do nothing
}
```

However, it only works in newer versions of JavaScript and older ones will throw a `SyntaxError`. So, you must be using an older version of Node, because [optional catch binding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding) is only available in Node.js v10+.

The following is an example in Node v8:

```js
// using Node v8
try { error } catch { console.log('oops') }
```

⬇<sup><sub>⬇ result ⬇</sub></sup>⬇

```sh
try { error } catch { console.log('oops') }
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

While it just works fine in Node v10+:

```js
// using Node v16
try { error } catch { console.log('oops') }
```

⬇<sup><sub>⬇ result ⬇</sub></sup>⬇

```sh
oops
```

To solve this, you need to [update your Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191466/6126373) to at least v12, as mentioned in the [discord.js docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start):

> v12 requires Node 12.x or higher, so make sure you're up-to-date. To
> check your Node version, use node -v in your terminal or command
> prompt, and if it's not high enough, update it! There are many
> resources online to help you with this step based on your host system.