# How to use date-fns in a Node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-fns

I installed date-fns as per the following instruction on https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns

```
npm install date-fns --save
```

After that my `package.json` is updated with the following entry:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0"
  }
}
```

Then, I wrote the following code from https://date-fns.org/ and it resulted in error:

```
import { format, formatDistance, formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), "'Today is a' eeee")
```

**Error:**

```
import { format, formatDistance, formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.143 seconds
```

**`node -v`:**

```
v12.2.0
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are probably facing a syntax errors. You are missing semicolons at the end of each line. The lines you copied are just abstract statements that can be used in code.

Comment: @Salvino - No, I have tried that as well but anyway, unlike Java, JavaScript does not require a semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: Can you also tell us, what is the command you are using to execute your code?

Comment: I am clicking the run button in VSCode. I also tried `node main.js` on the terminal but encountered the same error.

Comment: can you `cd` to your project's root directory and run `node main.js` in your terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to run it successfully by using `require` as shown below:

```
const fns = require('date-fns')

console.log(fns.format(new Date(), "'Today is a' eeee"))
```

**Update:**

I installed node v16.6.1 following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/10819573) and now I can run the following code successfully:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

console.log(format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing syntax errors, as you directly copy pasted the code from the documentation. Try importing the library as follows. It should work just fine.

```js
import { format, formatDistance, formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns';

const mDate= format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
console.log(mDate);
```

Comment: I am quite sure it does require semicolons at least for the import statements. Can you try the code in my answer?

Comment: Salvino - I did try your code but the error persists.

Comment: Can you delete the `node_modules` folder and try running `npm install` and see if that works? Because the node js version you are running is quite sufficient for running date-fns without any issues. I have used date-fns tones of times and didn't face any issues with the above code.

Comment: Salvino - I deleted `node_modules` folder and executed `npm install date-fns --save` which recreated this folder but the problem remains as it is.  I am quite new to node-js and probably missing some basic step.