# Why am I getting a ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined in Discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Today (7.8.2021) [Discord.js v13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) has been released. So I upgraded my previous [Discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) installation with

> `npm i discord.js@latest`

and then adapted my basic *index.js* file to this state (I followed the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#logging-in-to-discord)):

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

client.login("my-token");
```

However when I try to run my code I keep getting this error:

> $ node .
>
> (node:11216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined
>
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\*pathTo*\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:172:15)

I've been working with [Discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) since 2018, hence I was astonished that I was having trouble with the new release.
Is this an issue with the [Discord.js v13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) library? If not how can I fix the error?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: ^^ `AbortContoller` was only added to the Node.js API in v15: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_class_abortcontroller

Comment: I was using v14.15.4. Just updated my Node version. It's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### The Issue:

One of the [prerequisites](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html) for using Discord.js v13 is that you need to use NodeJS v16.6 or higher (emphasis mine):

> **v13 requires Node 16.6 or higher** to use, so make sure you're up to
> date. To check your Node version, use node -v

---

#### The Fix:

The fix is to update your node version, you can confirm your current node version by running `node -v`. There are a [variety of different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8191459/5648954) to update node, one way is to run the following commands if you're using Linux / iOS:

```
> npm install -g n
> n latest
```

The first command installs the command-line interface [n](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#n), and then the second uses `n` to update to the latest stable version of node. If you're on Windows, you can install [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191466/5648954) by [pradeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514873/pradeek).

**Note for Heroku users**:

Once you have followed the above steps to update your node version, you might then be required to update your `package.json` file by adding/updating the engines:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x"
}
```

---

#### Why this broke in v13?:

A few versions ago of discordjs, a feature was added that aborts requests that take too long (longer than 15 seconds). In order to achieve this functionality, they were previously using the node package [abort-controller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abort-controller). However, now that nodejs has evolved, it now has its own [AbortController](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_class_abortcontroller) global without the need to require an external package. Discord.js v13 now relies on this global as they're [no longer using the abort controller package](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/commit/d5e28c22988376825d5e11fbdcf2e99ba8ebc2f4). In order to use the `AbortController` global provided by nodejs, you need to be using node v15 or higher - however, as recommended by the discord.js guide, you should be using v16.6+ to enable support for other features it may use.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to install node.js v16 in all your system, and just add it in your bot's project, you can do:

```sh
npm install node@16.6.1 --save-exact
```

And it will run.

Answer (score 0):

N, the updater used in the solution, doesn't work for Windows operating systems.
If you use Windows there is still a way to update.
Go to the [Node.JS installation website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)

If you go there manually without clicking the link I provided, you will need to switch from the LTS option to Current. [image: as seen here]

^ as seen here

Choose the MSI installer and the architecture of which your old Node.JS version was installed with.

If you don't know the architecture of which your old Node.JS version was installed with you can check by checking if the nodejs folder is in "C:/Program Files" or "C:/Program Files (x86)"

Then just install Node.JS as if it was the first time.

Enjoy!