# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

I have recently update my Discord Bot code from js v12 to v13 and my node.js is up to date. I'm running my Bot on Heroku and when i push new changes, the error pops up saying `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined`. When i check my node version in VS Code, it says `v16.7.0` but in heroku log says, `v14.17.5`. The code works fine when ran from VS Code

Discord.js Version: v13.0.1
Node.js Version: v16.7.0

Comment: Does this answer your question [Why am I getting a ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined in Discord.js v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693319/why-am-i-getting-a-referenceerror-abortcontroller-is-not-defined-in-discord-js)?

Comment: Nope. I already have the latest version of node.js and djs. Everything works fine til i push this changes to heroku. In heroku log, it says im not using the latest version of node.js but in reality im

Comment: Are you able to log into Heroku and verify that the file that contains your Controller is indeed present?

Comment: @faso Yes, i can log in to my Heroku but how do i verify?

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68705951/5648954

Answer (score 0):

For Discord.js V13 u need the current Node.js version (`v16.7.0`), but Heroku will automatically take Node.js v14.17.5 if you didn't include an 'engines' tag in your package.json, from which it can get your desired node.js version.

You can pass this tag in your package.json like this:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.7.0"
  }
```

More information: [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)