# Why does the client in discord have an error that outputs: TypeError: [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS] in node.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I made a directory and then added a package.json file. I installed dotenv and discord.js on the package.json file. I made a src folder inside the directory and then put the bot.js file inside this src folder. The code was:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {

})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I typed in node ./src/bot.js and an error popped up. It said "node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');"

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Discord.js v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start) it is mandatory to pass [Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) to a new [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) instance. So in order to fix the error pass the minimum required Intents as an argument to your `client`:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.on("ready", () => {});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

> To specify which events you want your bot to receive, first think about which events your bot needs to operate. Then select the required intents and add them to your client constructor, as shown below.
>
> All gateway intents, and the events belonging to each, are listed on the [Discord API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried this code but it gives me an error and says that "Intents" are not defined.

Comment: Ah sorry, that is because I forgot to import the `Intents` from `discord.js`. I adapted my answer. Sorry about that...‍♂️

Comment: I imported Intents from discord.js and copy and pasted your code but I still get an error.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined.

Comment: Luckily you aren't the first person to encounter that problem ;) I have authored a question on exactly that issue: [Why am I getting a ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined in Discord.js v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693319/why-am-i-getting-a-referenceerror-abortcontroller-is-not-defined-in-discord-js)