# Discord Missing Intent Error on discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Im having trouble launching my code for the past 6 hours it was working fine yesterday but it doesnt seem to work any more i keep on having an error that says ('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENT')
[image]

this is my starting code i dont understand what i am doing wrong

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    welcome = require('./welcome'),
    mute = require('./mute'),
    unmute = require('./unmute'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Levels = require("discord-xp")


    

    const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the client in discord have an error that outputs: TypeError: \[CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS\] in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711304/why-does-the-client-in-discord-have-an-error-that-outputs-typeerror-client-mi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite literally missing an `Intent`. As you're probably already aware based on your code, v13 of discord.js requires you to add certain Intents to avoid processing power being thrown away to features not used.

You can look at all Intents available [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents), and try to add a few of them to see which one you need. Based on your code I can't see which one you're missing.