# CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS Discord.js V13

Tags: discord.js

So I recently got this error when updated my bot from discord.js V12 to V13. I know I updated discord.js to V13 as it is in my package.json. I have no idea why this is not working. I even added every Intents there is for discord.

**index.js code**

```js
const { Collection, MessageEmbed, Intents} = require("discord.js");
const token = process.env['TOKEN']
const server = require('./server.js');
const fs = require("fs")
const MongoClient = require('./utils/MongoClient');
const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS);
const bot = new MongoClient({ intents: myIntents});
```

**package.json code**

```js
{
   "name": "switch",
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "description": "Switch is a all new bot for discord!",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
      "start": "node index.js"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
      "mongoose": "^6.0.5"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "node": "^16.6.1"
   }
}
```

**Error**

```js
/home/runner/switch-beta-test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at MongoClient._validateOptions (/home/runner/switch-beta-test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (/home/runner/switch-beta-test/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
    at new MongoClient (/home/runner/switch-beta-test/utils/MongoClient.js:12:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/switch-beta-test/index.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Missing Intent Error on discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958672/discord-missing-intent-error-on-discord-js)

Comment: Is `MongoClient` your extended discord.js client or the connection script to your mongodb?

Comment: My `MongoClient` handles all the functions for the mongodb and to connect to the database, in discord.js V12 I was able to use the intents right from my index.js. As I saw what was wrong I moved my intents to my `MongoClient` file fixing my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems due to discord.js updating the Intents I had to move my intents to my mongoClient where I actually create the client to run all systems.

**MongoClient.js**

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const botconfig = require('../botconfig')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const economy = require('../models/EconomyModel');
const ItemManager = require('./ItemManager');
const channel = require('../models/ModerationModel.js');
const prefix = require('../models/ModerationModel.js');
const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS);

class MongoClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super({intents: myIntents});
```

The error not longer occurrs due to the intents being initialized with the Client itself.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js has been updated to v13 and lot of stuff changed as well.
Easiest way to do it:

```
const { Collection, MessageEmbed, Intents} = require("discord.js");
const token = process.env['TOKEN']
const server = require('./server.js');
const fs = require("fs")
const MongoClient = require('./utils/MongoClient');
const bot = new MongoClient({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        etc..
    ]
});
```

You need to look at this before you start updating your bot to v13.
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start

Answer (score 0):

I actually recommend another way that's shorter and is (I believe) better memory management.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
});
```

This should also solve your error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).