# Got this code off github, Tried to run it and threw this error, From what i could see, the error was in index.js and i provided the index.js code here

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
The Error:
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\User\Desktop\pnp music\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\User\Desktop\pnp music\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\pnp music\index.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

My code: (index.js)

```
//Importing all needed Commands
const Discord = require("discord.js"); //this is the official discord.js wrapper for the Discord Api, which we use!
const colors = require("colors"); //this Package is used, to change the colors of our Console! (optional and doesnt effect performance)
const Enmap = require("enmap"); //this package is our Database! We will use it to save the data for ever!
const fs = require("fs"); //this package is for reading files and getting their inputs

//Creating the Discord.js Client for This Bot with some default settings ;) and with partials, so you can fetch OLD messages
const client = new Discord.Client({
  fetchAllMembers: false,
  restTimeOffset: 0,
  shards: "auto",
  restWsBridgetimeout: 100,
  disableEveryone: true,
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
});

require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
process.setMaxListeners(100);

//Loading files, with the client variable like Command Handler, Event Handler, ...
["clientvariables", "command", "events", "erelahandler", "requestreacts"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});

//Each Database gets a own file and folder which is pretty handy!
client.premium = new Enmap({ name: "premium", dataDir: "./databases/premium" })
client.stats = new Enmap({ name: "stats", dataDir: "./databases/stats" })
client.settings = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/settings" })
client.setups = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/setups" })
client.queuesaves = new Enmap({ name: "queuesaves", dataDir: "./databases/queuesaves", ensureProps: false})
client.modActions = new Enmap({ name: 'actions', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });
client.userProfiles = new Enmap({ name: 'userProfiles', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });

//login into the bot
client.login(require("./botconfig/config.json").token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the client in discord have an error that outputs: TypeError: \[CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS\] in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68711304/why-does-the-client-in-discord-have-an-error-that-outputs-typeerror-client-mi)

Answer (score 0):

The Discord API was updated to require bots to declare their [Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) in order to receive certain events, this can be defined in the `intents` key within the table passed when creating a new `Client()`.

This should work as intended:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"); //this is the official discord.js wrapper for the Discord Api, which we use!
const colors = require("colors"); //this Package is used, to change the colors of our Console! (optional and doesnt effect performance)
const Enmap = require("enmap"); //this package is our Database! We will use it to save the data for ever!
const fs = require("fs"); //this package is for reading files and getting their inputs

//Creating the Discord.js Client for This Bot with some default settings ;) and with partials, so you can fetch OLD messages
const client = new Discord.Client({
  fetchAllMembers: false,
  restTimeOffset: 0,
  shards: "auto",
  restWsBridgetimeout: 100,
  disableEveryone: true,
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] // Declare the intents of your bot here.
});

require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
process.setMaxListeners(100);

//Loading files, with the client variable like Command Handler, Event Handler, ...
["clientvariables", "command", "events", "erelahandler", "requestreacts"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});

//Each Database gets a own file and folder which is pretty handy!
client.premium = new Enmap({ name: "premium", dataDir: "./databases/premium" })
client.stats = new Enmap({ name: "stats", dataDir: "./databases/stats" })
client.settings = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/settings" })
client.setups = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/setups" })
client.queuesaves = new Enmap({ name: "queuesaves", dataDir: "./databases/queuesaves", ensureProps: false})
client.modActions = new Enmap({ name: 'actions', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });
client.userProfiles = new Enmap({ name: 'userProfiles', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });

//login into the bot
client.login(require("./botconfig/config.json").token);
```