# How can I solve login error on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js');
    const { token } = require('./config.json');
    
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
    
    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });
    
    client.login(token);
```

I have this code, every time i try to run it returns me the same error:

> (node:13284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError:
> AbortController is not defined
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Luis\Vainas\Pruebas\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:172:15)
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Luis\Vainas\Pruebas\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:176:19)
> at RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Luis\Vainas\Pruebas\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:25)
> at async WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\Luis\Vainas\Pruebas\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:128:9)
> at async Client.login (C:\Users\Luis\Vainas\Pruebas\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:245:7)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created)       (node:13284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch().  To terminate the node
> process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:13284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Dont know how to fix it. I tried and investigate on the documentation but cant find the solution.
I've added this line to my code to find the error:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
});
```

Getting this:

> {   code: 500,   method: 'get',   path: '/gateway/bot',   requestData:
> { json: undefined, files: [] } }

Comment: You need to update node to atleast 16.6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined in Discord.js v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693319/why-am-i-getting-a-referenceerror-abortcontroller-is-not-defined-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

The `AbortController` package was introduced in Node.js v16 (?). So you need to upgrade your Node.js version. Discord.js v13 requires you to use Node.js v16 and higher as stated in their [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Depending on your operating system, you can either install 64bits or 32bits version of Node.js. Head over to the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) and download `16.8.x` (Current, Latest Features) Windows installer.

After installation, verify the version by typing `node -v` in your console.