# Discord.JS bot on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

Yesterday I've created a Discord bot using Discord.JS and it's working properly when I'm using my bot locally but after hosting it on Heroku it's not working anymore and the bot is offline.
In Heroku logs I can see this:

```
2021-09-15T13:39:08.604792+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-15T13:39:10.850210+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-09-15T13:39:11.455306+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-09-15T13:39:12.189682+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-09-15T13:39:12.264472+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039073+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039088+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:172:15)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039088+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:176:19)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039088+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.push (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:25)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039089+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async WebSocketManager.connect (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:128:9)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039089+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:245:7)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039090+00:00 app[worker.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039423+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2021-09-15T13:39:12.039451+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I completely don't know what is the reason for that error.
If anyone could help me I would be glad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions was already answered in another question. [Answer by Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693319/why-am-i-getting-a-referenceerror-abortcontroller-is-not-defined-in-discord-js). Basically, you have to change your node version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had a problem with specifying the node version but I've changed it in package.json file by adding   ``` "engines": {
    "node": "v16.9.1"
  }, ```