# Discord Bot not going online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("bot is ready");
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

OUTPUT

```
HTTPError [ReferenceError]: AbortController is not defined
    at RequestHandler.execute (g:\goofy-translator\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:172:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (g:\goofy-translator\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:176:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (g:\goofy-translator\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:25)
    at async WebSocketManager.connect (g:\goofy-translator\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:128:9)
    at async Client.login (g:\goofy-translator\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:245:7) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot',
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

The error is caused by client.login() method.Already triple checked the bot token and all seems fine. The problem isn't in the enviroment varible either, because also doesn't work when I pass the token directly.

[Resolved]
The problem was the node version, discord.js requires v16 min

Comment: There is not much I can do if all you are saying is that it throws an error. Log the error and see what it says.

Comment: The error is caused in the client.login()

Comment: Yes I know that, but you need to actually log the error thats causing the problem

Comment: I printed the exception, if thats what you were talking about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined in Discord.js v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693319/why-am-i-getting-a-referenceerror-abortcontroller-is-not-defined-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 13 of Discord.js, the library requires that you use a more recent Node.js version. According to the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/#installing-node-js), you need to use Node.js version v16.6.0 or higher.

For more information about how to change your node version, or use multiple node versions, see [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) or [NVM for Linux](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) depending on your OS.