# @slack/bolt requires at least version 12.13.0 of Node

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to use @slack/bolt api with React.js. I receive this error

`index.js:11 @slack/bolt requires at least version 12.13.0 of Node, please upgrade`

I upgraded npm to the latest version.

Comment: What you mentioned is that you have upgraded 'npm'. Did you also upgareded 'node'? May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js

Comment: Thank you, yes, I updated Node also.