# Error when running SvelteKit’s skeleton app locally

Tags: sveltekit

I am very new to programming and I have chosen to learn sveltekit. I am following this YouTube tutorial however he lost me when my skeleton project was not working!

Here is the output that I received in the terminal `$ npm run dev

> client@0.0.1 dev /home/runner/svelte-chat/client
> svelte-kit dev

file:///home/runner/svelte-chat/client/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/cli.js:861
https = https || !!vite_config.server?.https;
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.0.1 dev: `svelte-kit dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-11-30T00_11_38_289Z-debug.log `

Any help at all is appreciated as I am a total beginner. I am using a MacBook Pro 13” running MacOS Monterey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SvelteNewbie.

Please take time to properly display the code and the error messages in your post.

The solution to your problem is to simply update your node version (please perform background research before posting your question to stack overflow).

To update your node version, refer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js).

Hope this helps and enjoy your programming journey!

Comment: I feel so ashamed right now, I wasn’t thinking about my node version being out of date, I thought it was to do with the apple m1 SoC. Thank you sir

Comment: @sveltenewbie  Did you note Pawel’s comments on properly displaying code and errors?  Hint:  use the edit button on the bottom of your question.