# Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I don't know how, but the following error has been appearing on starting my app from `npm start` and is preventing me from building the project with `npm run build`. I have researched a lot and tried many methods but still have no luck in getting rid of this error. I have tried installing the previous version of the related packages appearing in the error, and I also deleted the `node_modules` folder and re-installed the packages with `npm install` but still no luck. So yeah I can't understand the error but need help resolving this.

`Error Message:`

```
Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'eslint/use-at-your-own-risk'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\amand\Documents\_My Files\app\frontend_react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\util\getESLintCoreRule.js
- C:\Users\amand\Documents\_My Files\app\frontend_react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\rules\brace-style.js
- C:\Users\amand\Documents\_My Files\app\frontend_react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\rules\index.js
- C:\Users\amand\Documents\_My Files\app\frontend_react\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\eslint-plugin\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\amand\Documents\_My Files\app\frontend_react\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
```

`package.json:`

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@horat1us/detect-ad-block": "^1.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.1.1",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.25",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/swiper": "^5.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.0.0",
    "react-request-fullscreen": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "swiper": "^8.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=8080 HTTPS=true && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.20.0",
    "eslint": "^8.14.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reading the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11856

You can try to update your node.js version.

Comment: Hmmm okay. How do I update the node version? What is the node command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I simply had to uninstall the existing `Node.js` and install the latest version. Errors simply stopped appearing.