# I want to continue developing with ionic 6 however the new project is creating an ionic 7 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I want to create an ionic 6 project.
My ionic-cli version is 6.20.9 installed globally.

Recently it was upgraded to 7 therefore, I removed the cli and installed it again using this command

```
ionic uninstall @ionic/cli
ionic instal @ionic/cli@6
```

Now, I can see the ionic version is 6.20.9

Then, I start a new project using

```
ionic start projectName tabs --type=ionic-angular --capacitor
```

This is creating a new project. However, it's going for ionic 7.

Here is my info
[image]
Here is my package.json
[image]

I noticed that I don't have an ionic framework installed in my info list.

Comment: Any luck on this ? I too am facing the same issue

Comment: No, I am still looking forward for a better way of doing it.

Comment: Anyone who has done such an activity then please let me know.

Comment: Kiran, we too had same issue and so took the repo from previous ionic-angular 6 project and started building the code on top of it.

Comment: Even I am doing the same and started work on v6 code base till there are any simpler steps to follow, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and finally removed it successfully, Could help someone so I put my solution here.

I was on Nodejsv16.10 so firstly I updated my Node.js which ionic7 supports. I updated it to Node.js@18.17.1

Then follow this Stackoverflow solution for updating Node.js(it is very clear):

[How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

Finally, follow this code to uninstall:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

or if you install with ionic/cli then do :

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Now, you will remove ionic successfully.