# is 'npm install -g npm' installing npm redundant?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am coming from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756898/4126424) and I am wondering how this approach `npm install -g npm` is handled on my machine. Will I end up with two versions of npm (and node after also doing `npm install -g node`)? Is this a clean solution or will it lead to unexpected side effects due to different versions on my machine? If not, why? What is happening under the hood?