Resolve this cryptic error to generate an image from OpenAI using JS?
Objective: Common Objective of Requesting and Receiving Text-To-Image Generation from OpenAI using plain JavaScript and Displaying it to the User of the Script or Program.
This is the relevant code section that was put together:

const fs = require('fs'); // Import file system module

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({apiKey: "<!--insert your key string here : redacted by OP-->"});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

try {
  const response = openai.createImage({
    prompt: "A cool memory from 90s Television",
    n: 2,
    size: "1024x1024"
  });
  
  const imageData = response.data.data[0].url; // Assuming response contains image URL
  
  fs.writeFileSync('image.png', imageData, { encoding: 'base64' }); // Save as base64 encoded PNG
  console.log("Image saved to image.png");
  
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}


Result:
We receive a SyntaxError in the installed module file.
I suspect this is something wrong with the code, perhaps in the way I have initialised or dealt with the OpenAIApi object. However, I'm open to receiving your diagnosis and subsequent rectification.
This is the error message produced when I run it with node v10.19.0
<dir_path>/node_modules/openai/index.js:51
    constructor({ baseURL = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_BASE_URL'), apiKey = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_API_KEY'), organization = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_ORG_ID') ?? null, project = Core.readEnv('OPENAI_PROJECT_ID') ?? null, ...opts } = {}) {
                                                                                                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nik/Desktop/img.js:3:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)

This is a module error, I can't be expected to solve this alone.
I have only ever come across ? in the sense of nullability and in ternary operator.
I'm using openai@4.44.0 installed with npm 6.14.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
Please provide anything relevant. All discussion is welcome to prove this objective.

Additional Bonus Question (optional):
Rather than saving the file, I'd really like it to pop a window into view, or within the terminal if that is possible now, when I run node filename.js where filename.js is the JavaScript file where I have saved this code.
I tried running the code several times, changing things here and there without any difference in error output. Currently, I am trying to consult StackOverflow. I did not find this particular error response and find it unusual and hindering the DX. Posting this question, I was expecting resolution of the problem so I can run the program with the intended output.

Nullish coalescing was first supported in node 14.5
https://node.green/
Upgrade.

Command 'nvm' not found and nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1.6).

@NikhilKartha I can assure you that 10.19.0 is not the newest version of nodejs. I also never mentioned using nvm anywhere. I'm guessing you went here and copied the install on linux using nvm. The answer to your question is that you must upgrade to a node version that supports nullish coalescing. If you want to know how to upgrade on linux, then go look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js
