# How do I update npm in linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

[image]

I've tried the following in order to update npm. But no commands seem to work. 
What should I do so I can update npm?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-for-the-next-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`npm update`](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-update.html) command updates all packages (no arguments), a specific package (with a package name as argument); in the local directory or in the global modules directory (`-g` argument).

As stated in the [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#How-do-I-update-npm), sometimes the `npm update npm -g` command doesn't work, especially if you run an old version of npm, which you are. To really update npm, run this:

```bash
$ curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: When I trie your command it says I should update node first. Is there also an .sh file to update node?

Comment: You can use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage Node versions: install it, then run `$ nvm install 0.10`.