# How to update npm

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to install mean.io boilerplate. It fails when running `sudo npm install -g meanio@latest`. Prior to failing it notes that it 'wants' npm version 1.4.x, whereas I have 1.2.18 installed.  So I tried updating npm to the latest; several ways.  Last of which was...

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ sudo npm install -g npm
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@1.4.7 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ npm --version
1.2.18
```

Why is it still showing version 1.2.18, when I just updated to 1.4.7?

Comment: Do `sudo npm update npm -g`

Comment: If you can risk the use of an unsupported PPA, try https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

Comment: sudo npm install npm -g helped me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: This should be on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

Answer (score 245):

This will update **npm** using **npm** itself:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

If you are stuck, try `sudo npm update npm -g`. All credit goes to Tim Castelijns. I have *tested it on ubuntu 14.04, npm 1.3.10*

---

Note that if you are using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for *managing multiple versions in your local dev environment for e.g. testing purposes*, all your installed versions (listed by `nvm ls`) are in ~/.nvm, hence you just omit system wide installation (i.e. omit sudo):

```
npm install npm -g
```

---

**DEBIAN ENTERPRISE**

For full enterprise practice consider **[nodesource.com](http://nodesource.com)**:

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -

as described [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/chris-lea-joins-forces-with-nodesource).

**OTHER ENTERPRISE**

For non-debian distributions check out  on the node <strike>github wiki
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager</strike> download page https://nodejs.org/en/download/

For historical understanding: Chis Lea was maintaining his PPA but now [joined forces](https://nodesource.com/blog/chris-lea-joins-forces-with-nodesource) with *nodesource*.

Comment: I'd recommend using a PPA repository so you let ubuntu package manager maintain the updates along with everything else.

Comment: On sort of production servers, yes, maybe. But on dev you really want to guarantee you get stuff directly from the npm package maintainer, not the PPA maintainer

Comment: I disagree. You don't want dev to be different from production or you will run into deployment issues for different versions.

Comment: Again depending on how paranoid you are, trusting Chis Lea's PPA might be questionable. There is  always a decision possible on how much of the critical dependencies in the project one just offloads as a local copy. If you are not working in the bank but doing an open source project you might not even have a production to worry about :) I will link the node wiki here just listing all the alternatives. Personally I am not a big of PPA vs. github tags when it comes to code distribution.

Comment: Don't need to use Chris's PPA. Use the official one from node source.

Comment: ok. check my last edit. Please feel free to fix it if required ;)

Comment: Apparently https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm is a great option to manage multiple node versions.

Answer (score 52):

if user3223763's answer doesn't works, you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs ^node-* nodejs-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Then :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | sh
```

After this, open a new terminal and check the npm version:

```
npm --version
```

## EDIT / UPDATE :

Today the last nvm version is :

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh

Thus the CURL command is: v0.25.4 instead of v0.13.1

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | sh
```

> You can check https://github.com/creationix/nvm/releases to use the correct version for further upgrades

Comment: user3223763 didn't work for me, neither did self updating npm. Thank you Daniel

Comment: I can confirm this method helped update npm. Previous methods had libraries unmet dependencies or would update npm but would not update the path/environment to use the new location.

Comment: This also worked for me, the other answers did not on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: This worked for me using Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Chromebook with Crouton. Nothing else I'd found online worked

Comment: Does npm requires nvm for instalation?

Answer (score 27):

don't forget to close and start the terminal window again ;)

(at least if you want to check "npm --version" in the terminal)

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

that did the trick for me, too

Comment: the 'close and start the terminal again' part is what I was missing. thank you

Answer (score 26):

Tried the options above on Ubuntu 14.04, but they would constantly produce this error:

> npm ERR! tar pack Error reading
>   /root/tmp/npm-15864/1465947804069-0.4854120113886893/package

Then found this solution online:

1) Clean the cache of npm first:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

2) Install **n** module of npm:

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

3) Begin the installation by selecting the version of node to install: **stable** or **latest**, we will use **stable** here:

```
sudo n stable
```

4) Check the version of node:

```
node -v
```

5) Check the version of npm:

```
npm -v
```

Comment: This answer could use some expanding to explain what the less obvious commands are doing.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you are using Ubuntu (from the command line you show). To update `npm` and `nodejs` you can use the PPA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Comment: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
` for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Comment: to get rid of the annoying error run :
 rm  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cooperjona-ubuntu-nitrotasks-bionic.list

Answer (score 11):

To get the latest stable version just run

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

It worked just fine for me!

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

Answer (score 6):

## You can use `npm` package manager:

```
npm install npm@latest
```

This installs `npm` using itself @ latest version.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple

For Linux or Mac

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

For Windows: Run your command prompt as administrator and run the command below

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 3):

## upgrading to nodejs v0.12.7

```
 # Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
 curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

 # Then install with:
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[Source from nodesource.com](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories)

Answer (score 3):

For me It worked with following commands

1. $curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
2. $apt install nodejs

Refer : https://linuxhint.com/how-to-update-npm-packages/

Answer (score 3):

NPM was returning the old version after running `$ sudo npm install npm -g`.

Restarting the terminal (i.e. close and open again) fixed the issue for me and `$ npm --version` began returning the expected version.

<sub>* @Rimian mentions the need to reload the terminal in a comment of another answer.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Check your node version **node -v** and your **npm** version **npm -v** Then To update your **npm**, type this into your terminal :
 **sudo npm install npm@latest -g**

*N.B: Debian Based OS{ubuntu or Linux mint}*

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

This worked for me in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to update npm to a specific version, you can use this :

`npm install npm@version-number`

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i -g npm

      Update available 4.5.0 → 4.6.1    │
   │     Run npm i -g npm to update
```

this is what npm recommends when in terminal, second piece is directly copied and pasted from my terminal

note: im using a mac

Comment: The question is specifically about ubuntu, not osx. If I tried your command in ubuntu, `npm` will fails with  `Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'`. You should remove your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your node version `node -v` and your npm version `npm -v`
Then To update your npm, type this into your terminal:
`npm install npm@latest -g`

Hope I could help. Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on ubuntu
`curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh`

Answer (score 0):

```
nvm install-latest-npm
```

if you happen to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the cache of npm first:

   sudo npm cache clean -f
2. Install n module of npm:

   sudo npm install -g n
3. Begin the installation by selecting the version of node to install: stable or latest, we will use stable here:

   sudo n stable
4. Check the version of the node:

   node -v
5. Check the version of npm:

   npm -v

I hope both the node and npm version is updated now. If it's not updated then please restart your machine and check it again :)

Comment: why do folks use the "n" package, when all you have to do is `npm install npm@latest` ?  what's the advantage ?

Answer (score 0):

**Updating npm and node.js**

You may get latest versions from snap store

```
sudo apt remove nodejs ^node-* nodejs-*
snap install node --classic
```

This on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS gave me

```
node -v  ==> v18.17.1
npm -v   ==> 9.6.7
```

Note that the latest npm version may also need a newer node.js version.
Also, running on Ubuntu LTS version vs the newest release also may limit the node/npm versions that run on your setup.

Answer (score -2):

For Ubuntu 18.04

## npm install latest-version

I hope its for you also