# Unable to update npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This Error keeps happening for me when i'm trying to update **NPM** for some work. I have used this always it before in **Windows Command Prompt** but not in **Linux Bash**

**npm i -g npm**

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
/root/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@5.6.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
root@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~# npm -v
5.6.0
root@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~# npm i -g npm
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename \'/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each\' -> \'/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/stream-each',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/mississippi/node_modules/.stream-each.DELETE',
npm ERR!   parent: 'mississippi' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-21T13_00_43_617Z-debug.log
```

Some details on my environment:

1) I used Windows Subsystem for Linux Platform for installation of Node.js

2) I tried it while I was in root only.

3) I tried to update the NPM package using some command shown in this [NPM update Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393707/how-to-update-npm)

But Still not able to perform the update. It shows the following error

```
root@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~# npm install npm -g
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
root@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~#
```

I'm stuck to even proceed further. Is there something that can be done to clear up this error and update NPM ?

Edit No 2:

I have tried to reinstall Node.js and NpM but below error pops up

```
ash@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
[sudo] password for ash:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can you guys provide me any technique to reinstall both Node.js and NPM?

Comment: did you try running `sudo npm install npm -g`?

Comment: @PrashantBaid I'm sudo mode. I tried updating while using the above command mentioned only. Still was not working .

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean cache of npm
**sudo npm cache clean -f**

And then, Update command
**npm install -g npm**

then, to remove vulnerable

**npm audit fix --force**

Answer (score 0):

The command output is:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

It seems that npm does not exist in your system for some reason.
Try reinstalling NodeJS.