# I cannot run npm install

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I've dual Boot(ubuntu/Windows 10) on my laptop.
I am getting this error and I can't run npm install on Ubuntu. I checked with node -v and it shows v17.4.0
:

```
npm does not support Node.js v13.14.0

npm ERR! Invalid or unexpected token

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/diana/.npm/_logs/2022-02-12T09_42_18_704Z-debug-0.log
```

Update: I had to uninstall and remove all the folders related to node and npm. I've also installed the latest version of nvm 0.39 and only then I managed to actually upgrade the node to the right version. Everything is working now.

[How can I completely uninstall nodejs, npm and node in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu/60701804#60701804)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your npm?

If no, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm
```

or check this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393707/how-to-update-npm#:~:text=sudo%20add%2Dapt%2Drepository%20ppa%3Achris%2Dlea/node.js%0Asudo%20apt%2Dget%20update%0Asudo%20apt%2Dget%20install%20nodejs%20npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393707/how-to-update-npm#:%7E:text=sudo%20add%2Dapt%2Drepository%20ppa%3Achris%2Dlea/node.js%0Asudo%20apt%2Dget%20update%0Asudo%20apt%2Dget%20install%20nodejs%20npm)

Comment: I tried and it says: 
```
npm does not support Node.js v13.14.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
``
when I run node -v it shows v17.4.0

Comment: this should work:
sudo apt-get install -y npm