# Installing/updating npm & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an old version of NPM and NodeJS installed on my AWS server.  I really just need bower to work to install a module.  npm version is 1.1.0-2.  Node version is 0.6.8.

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Results in:

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.42-52.145.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-2
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: npm
```

Also tried NodeJS from source. README says use the usual ./configure, make, make install.  Caveat: no configure script. :-/

Ready to throw my hands up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update NodeJS and Npm for the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-for-the-next-versions)

Comment: Sort of but none of those are working.  I actually got the source to compile (I had downloaded the binaries by mistake).  So hopefully that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try running the following in your terminal:

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I think we have a chicken & the egg scenario. It downloads, but outdates this:

You are using an outdated and unsupported version of
node (v0.6.8).  Please update node and try again.

Comment: Is uninstalling and reinstalling node an option? Sounds like you're on a very old version of node.

Comment: I didn't see anything that looked like Node in yum.  (Disclaimer: Not a yum user).  Installing from source did sort it out though -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the source code eventually did work. I had downloaded the binaries by mistake.  (Odd that they come w/ a README telling you how to build the source code).

Hoping anyone else looking to upgrade can learn something from this.

Anywho, I'm good on this for now.  Thanks for the input.