# (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) - node installing error

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

When I run: `npm install -g sails`

I get this error/warning: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`

I have tried:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm update
npm install
```

nothing seems to work. I used to have sails up and running on my machine untill I uninstalled it. Now that I want to use it again it refuses to install the package. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe npm need to be updated, try this :

```
npm install -g npm
npm install -g sails
```

Look this post it may help [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Answer (score 1):

eventually I solved this by rebooting my windows machine and open the nodejs command prompt as an admin and installing sails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm install sails --msvs_version=2013 -g
```

The `--msvs_version=<.net version>` part should refer to the version of .NET you have installed on your windows pc.

Comment: what does .NET has to do with my node app?

Comment: Just try with the 2013 flag for now.

Comment: What does .NET have to do with anything?