# How can I update npm itself?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to update npm itself:

```
npm uninstall npm -g
```

Responds with:

```
unbuild npm@2.12.1
```

But when I go:

```
npm --version
```

I get 1.4.28? How to upgrade the npm itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and NPM to the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: It's not what you asked, but [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) solved my problems with npm installations

Answer (score 61):

By using this command you can update npm to the latest release by using npm itself :

```
 npm i -g npm@latest
```

Comment: NB: you may also need to upgrade node.  To do that, in an elevated session run `nvm install latest` then `nvp use latest`.

Answer (score 36):

You can try this:

> cd /usr/lib/node_modules
>
> npm install npm@latest

Edit:

`npm install -g npm` worked for me.

[image]

Comment: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js.

Answer (score 11):

See which version you have

```
npm -v
```

Install the newest npm update

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Upgrade to the most recent release

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

**Upgrading on Windows**
Microsoft wrote a small command-line tool to automate the steps below. You can go and [download it here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)

https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm