# Why doesn't "npm audit" CLI command run from Powershell in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, npm, npm-scripts

- NPM Version: 5.6.0
- Node Version: 8.11.4
- Windows 10: Powershell (VS Code terminal)

When I run the `npm audit` task in Powershell I get a prompt asking "Did you mean this? Edit"

I am running in the root directory of my project (with the package.json file) and other npm commands work as expected.

It appears that the command is not recognised. From what I can see in the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit this should work out of the box without any other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `npm audit` command was added in npm v6. [[1](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/173719309445/npm-audit-identify-and-fix-insecure)]

Node.js v10.3.0 was the first Node version to bundle npm v6 with it. Upgrading to Node v10.3.0 or later will get you npm v6 and `npm audit` support.

You can also upgrade your npm version independently of your Node.js version by running `npm install -g npm`. [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290581/7127751)]

Comment: This definitely looks like the issue. My only confusion is that I was able to do this until recently. I can only assume that I overrode my NPM installation with NPM ~6 but not my Node installation. Then, subsequently did a minor update to my Node version using NVM this then overwrote the NPM version back below 6.

Comment: Yeah, if you installed a different Node version, your npm version will probably change.

Comment: Dont forget to reopen your terminal :)