# Protractor unable to parse conf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor for e2e test my angular app, but getting:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'parse' when calling "protractor conf.js"

Here is the conf file content:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['HomePageCtrl_spec.js'],
chromeOnly: true,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
}
};
```

And here is the exception i am getting on running this command:

```
E:\eCOIGit\sidhome\SidHome\SidHome.Tests\ng-test-e2e>protractor Conf.js
```

Error:

> C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:12
>   6 throw e; **TypeError: Object # has no method 'parse'** at
>   Function.ConfigParser.resolveFilePatterns
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\
>   npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\configParser.js:102:29) at new
>   TaskScheduler
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\taskScheduler.js:31:31)
>   at
>   C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\launcher.js
>   :180:21 at _fulfilled
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
>   e_modules\q\q.js:797:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
>   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
>   at
>   C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:573:44
>   at flush
>   (C:\Users\xqwt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
>   ules\q\q.js:108:17)at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug in protractor, the issue is now fixed.

Currently you can get the version containing the fix by installing it directly from the master branch:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/angular/protractor.git
```

As a workaround, instead you can *update node to >=0.12*.

---

Here are the related issues from the `protractor` issue tracker:

- [TypeError: Object # has no method 'parse'](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2590)
- [Latest release requires node v0.12](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2588)
- [fix(configParser): Remove path.parse so protractor works with node <](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/2591)

---

Also see:

- [How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js)
- [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: I can't upgrade to version 0.12 yet, what version of protractor can I use for now so I don't have to upgrade right now?

Comment: @user1007983 I think you should be save with protractor 2.4.0.

Comment: @user1007983 btw, the issue is now fixed, which means you can install protractor dev version directly from the master branch.