# Why do I get old versions of nodejs and npm when installing with apt-get?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, apt-get

I have executed the following command in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs modejs-legacy npm
```

I have the versions

```
npm -v
1.3.10

nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

These are older than the recommended versions for AngularJS 2.

Why does apt-get download old version?
How do I update to newer versions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and NPM to the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6237295/710446). It doesn't answer the "why?" question, but that answer to that is, "because old version are what's in Canonical's software repositories for your version of Ubuntu"

Comment: Both Debian and RHEL distros have old versions of node and npm. Not sure why node isn't supporting their linux packages, but it sure makes running servers tricky.

Comment: has to do with LTS!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu has old version in their package manager, you have to use custom PPA repository as stated here:

> https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

Setup it with:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Then install with Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

Comment: This was the missing piece of the puzzle for me trying to install to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Doing this saves the linked repo with a higher priority than the Ubuntu's package manager's default?

Comment: Yes it will be overwritten by this

Comment: I understand this is an old thread, but would you happen to know why ubuntu/debian's package manager doesn't update this automatically?

Comment: Don't know, lazy maintainers?

Comment: This seems to answer the question of how to get the current version, not old versions.

Comment: in 2021 use `nvm` to install any node version

Comment: Adding a comment so that Google picks up the terms I used when searching: the `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for `import` statements is caused by the outdated version of `npm`.

Answer (score 5):

To get the latest version the easiest thing to do is install nvm. [nvm install instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installation-and-update)

1. install nvm `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash`
2. `nvm install v10.15.3`
3. (optional) set default `nvm alias default v10.15.3`