# Docker: npm not found

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, build, containers

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN mkdir /opt/public
RUN mkdir /opt/bin
ADD public /opt/public
ADD bin /opt/bin
RUN ls -lah /opt/bin
RUN ls -lah /opt/public
ADD run.sh /bin/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/run.sh
RUN cd /opt/bin && npm install
CMD ["/bin/run.sh"]
```

When I build the Container, I get this eror:

> /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

What is the problem? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try installing `npm` separately while building the image:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    npm                       # note this one
```

Comment: Thanks, I used "apt-get install npm -y" instead of "npm install". Everything is ok.

Comment: When I run docker, I get this error: Cannot find module 'localstorage-polyfill'
Do you have any solution?

Comment: It's probably because you cnahged `npm install` to `apt-get install npm`, while you need both

Comment: You are right. I wrote both in the Dockerfile. Everything is fine.

Comment: Did not work for me, i had to `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -` first.

Comment: @FabianPicone I also prefer that option,  but don't forget to install curl, or you'll get exactly the error outlined above :)

Answer (score 7):

`Node` also packages `npm`, so no need to install `npm` like mentioned by Yury. It's in general a bad idea to do it like that, because you don't have control over the `nodejs` and `npm` version

For me the answer was quite simple. I had the following code:

```
# install nodejs
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y \
  nodejs
RUN echo "Node: " && node -v
RUN echo "NPM: " && npm -v
```

but I for got to install curl, so it failed. So before this, you need to install curl:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
```

Comment: Great catch! I had the same gotcha

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone continues to run across this problem, it's likely due to [the package manager on the image's underlying OS specifying a version of node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594609/470477) that's so old that it doesn't include npm. Here's a modified version of the linked answer for a Dockerfile:

```
# This is needed to update the OS' package manager so that 
# the current version of node will be installed:
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -

RUN apt-get -yq update \
    && apt-get -yq upgrade \
    && apt-get install -yq nodejs \
    && npm --version
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case everything was working fine until I update the Docker and start getting this error.  So after try all the above solutions and none of them work, I changed the version of node image and this worked for me.

Before:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash -
```

After:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
```

Comment: Surprisingly this fixed my code. My Dockerfile was working for ages but suddenly started showing the npm not found. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps have already installed `node` and `npm` here. May be you need to run **npm/node** related script in a new interactive shell, after installing node packages through `curl`. So, in the last line, you may try:

```
CMD cat /bin/run.sh | bash -ic
```

Or

```
CMD bash -i /bin/run.sh
```

Or

```
CMD ["/bin/bash","-i","/bin/run.sh"]
```

Interactive bash for **npm/node** worked in my case and is invoked with `bash -i`

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. `RUN npm install` works, which means it is already installed. This magical `-i` worked somehow.

Answer (score 1):

**I was getting following error while building docker container:**

```
> [runtime  1/11] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | -E bash;        apt-get install -y nodejs;        npm i -g npm@8:
#11 0.360 /bin/sh: 1: -E: not found
#11 1.687 Reading package lists...
#11 1.696 Building dependency tree...
#11 1.698 Reading state information...
#11 1.703 E: Unable to locate package nodejs
#11 1.703 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

err: appname
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

**In dockerfile i changed:**

```
  RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
      && apt-get install -y nodejs \
      && npm i -g npm@8
```

**to this**

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    npm
```

**and container build succeeded**

Answer (score 1):

This is how you actually do it in 2023 if you are tying to get old node version on a debian version that defaults to newer version of node. for example, if you need node 8 on debian 10 via nodesource.

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs=8.17.0-1nodesource1
```

if you dont add `8.17.0-1nodesource1` it will still install the default ver available with debian 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines in Docker file before running any npm command.

```
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends apt-utils --yes \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends npm --yes
```