# NodeJS syntax error on linux but not on windows

Tags: node.js, linux, syntax

I wrote an external task client in nodejs for camunda bpm

```
const { Client, logger } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
const { Variables } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");

const config = { baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" };
const client = new Client(config);

client.subscribe("Rechnung", async function({ task, taskService }) {

  console.log("*** Processing task " + task.id);
  
  const processVariables = new Variables();

  await taskService.complete(task, processVariables);

});
```

It works when i run it on windows but on my ubuntu server i got a syntax error at the first line the first curly bracket.

[image]

Comment: What versions of Node?

Comment: Sorry i forgot about that, its v4.2.6

Comment: On both? That's also a pretty old version.

Comment: oh strange, i installed it half an hour ago via apt on a fresh ubunto vm :D

Comment: sorry no, on windows i have v16.15.1

Comment: Maybe its because first i installed node, then nodejs but i couldnt start it, then i installed nodejs-legacy because the error message told me to do so

Comment: You'll want to be running the same version on both, or at least compatible ones. Node 4 is ~6 years old.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did "apt update && apt install nodejs" it tells me "nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2)."

Comment: Just for completion i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594314/why-do-i-get-old-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-when-installing-with-apt-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your error is on a line of code using object destructuring.  That received full support in nodejs v6.  If you're running v4.2.6, that would explain why it's generating an error.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379277/destructuring-in-node-js), nodejs v4.1 had a command line argument `--harmony_destructuring` that would enable a pre-release version of object destructuring support.

Keep in mind that nodejs v4.2.6 is quite old (6 years old) which is considered ancient in this ecosystem and you're likely to run into other problems with other NPM modules too.