# Cannot update any npm package

Tags: npm

npm 3.9
Mac osx 10.11.5

When I do:

> npm cache clean
>
> sudo npm install npm -g

it does show progress bar, does its work, but npm is still 3.9.0, should be 3.9.2.

Also with package, for example:

> sudo npm update -g yo

Doesn't do anything. I'm returned to command line without any progress bar or operation details, and package is still old version.

Is there a known problem with npm registry ?

Comment: Maybe you have a proxy ?

Comment: hmm no, I never used, it always worked as is. Anyway to check ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions?rq=1

Comment: won't help, tried most of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that global update of some modules where prevented because of major version change. Since I don't know where / if  there is a global package.json... i wasn't sure.

> npm -g outdated

showed the problem.

Then I forced install of desired global module to specific version as:

> sudo npm install -g tslint@3.10.2