# updating npm doesn't work on my Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, npm, npm-install

First, I checked my `npm` version as following

```
$npm -v
2.10.1
```

then I tried updating it via `sudo npm install npm@latest -g` and checked it again, it still displayed as `2.10.1`, the latest version should be `4.5.0` though.

**UPDATE**
I know some of you might think this is a duplicated question, however, I tried the some of ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions), and then encountered the issue. still can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: @JackTaylor can't agree with you, the link you post doesn't describe the issue I encountered.