# npm run dev command does not work on vuejs' hackernews example

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to run the vue-hackernews-2.0 example from vuejs' github [repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0)

In setup section it explains how to install the project:

```
# install dependencies
npm install # or yarn

# serve in dev mode, with hot reload at localhost:8080
npm run dev

# build for production
npm run build

# serve in production mode
npm start
```

I did npm install. After changing the port to 8888 in server.js I typed "npm run dev" on command line.

```
> vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master
> node server

server started at localhost:8888


DONE  Compiled successfully in 16328ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1:02:18 PM


DONE  Compiled successfully in 17845ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1:02:19 PM


webpack built bd162a76119031a85eed in 17845ms
```

When I go localhost:8888 It will just try to load for 1 min and then it fails, without anything on the console.

I thought I should also try "npm run build" and "npm start" so I also used two commands. "npm run build" successfully created the dist file.

But after "npm start" I get this error:

```
> vue-hackernews-2.0@ start D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\server.js:41:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at notFoundError (D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\212399486\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vue-hackernews-2.0@ start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-hackernews-2.0@ start script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vue-hackernews-2.0 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vue-hackernews-2.0
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\212399486\WebstormProjects\vue-hackernews-2.0-master\npm-debug.log
```

Screenshot of dist folder:

[image]

package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "build": "rimraf dist && npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.client.config.js --progress --hide-modules",
    "build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.server.config.js --progress --hide-modules"
  },
```

Comment: Try executing `npm run build:server`

Comment: Has my answer been of any use?

Comment: @EMX I am trying to upgrade my npm (have proxy problems), I will update after it.

Comment: You also need to upgrade your nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Requires Node.js 7+

I managed to make it work without any problems.

```
$node -v
v8.3.0
$npm -v
5.3.0
```

## Change the default port successfully :

To change the default port you have to edit `package.json` scripts:

dev: `cross-env PORT=8888 node server`

start: `cross-env PORT=8888 NODE_ENV=production node server`

Then running `npm run dev`

```
> vue-hackernews-2.0@ dev /home/emx/so/vue-hackernews-2.0
> cross-env PORT=8888 node server

server started at localhost:8888
```

Comment: This is also what I see on console. But going localhost:8888 won't give me anything.

Comment: It's foolproof, try to start from scratch, clone the repo again, dont modify anything except the package.json...

Comment: Still won't open. these are from commandline: server started at localhost:8888,  DONE  Compiled successfully in 6111ms,  Compiled successfully in 7098ms , webpack built 8385a245ad885ee486c6 in 7098ms

Comment: try 127.0.0.1:8888 or 
in terminal do
`ifconfig | grep 192` find your local ip in the network try to open it in the browser with port `8888`

Comment: As my first line states "Node.js  7 Required" & @QuoVadis pointed out again... you need to update your node version. Remember that to change the port is editing the `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

you are using a version of node that is not supported. Your error point to `node v6.11.2` see below.

```
 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\212399486\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
 npm ERR! node v6.11.2
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
```

vue-hackernews-2.0 requires `Node.js 7+`. Upgrade your node to a 7+ version and you should be fine. I'll also recommend to update your npm version.

See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions) for details about how to update your node version, if you need instructions.