# I can not update my npm version

Tags: npm

Im using npm to update npm. It says that it updates it but the version stays the same (I have run this many times). Any help is appriciated.

```
felix:~/job (dev) $ npm --version
5.6.0

felix:~/job (dev) $ npm install npm@latest -g
/home/felix/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /home/felix/.npmglobal/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/home/felix/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /home/felix/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.1.0
updated 1 package in 4.939s

felix:~/job (dev) $ npm --version
5.6.0
```

I've also tried to do:

```
felix:~/job (dev) $ curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
module.js:549    curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.30077/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
removed 682 packages in 3.11s
/home/felix/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /home/felix/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/home/felix/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /home/felix/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.1.0
added 1 package from 572 contributors in 1.413s
It worked
felix:~/job (dev) $ npm --version
5.6.0
```

This also threw an error. And I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: @TheAlpha please check my update. I have followed that thread.

Comment: check also if you have the latest version of node.js as well. 
And try to remove node js + npm. Then install it fresh :)

Comment: @Sh.Pavel I have the latest stabel (`v8.11.3`). And have also tried to reinstall! Thanks!

Comment: working on linux machine ? If so - my advice also to run it via sudo npm install -g npm

Comment: I am running linux so unfortunately no. I dont think you should run npm with sudo!

Comment: I'd use a version manager. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Try using node version manager (nvm) to set node to latest version. https://davidwalsh.name/nvm

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem, even **npm view npm version** was returning 6.4.0 for me but **npm -v** still printed out 5.3.0.

Following this link: https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689 I uninstalled node from(with) Homebrew and reinstalled (still using Homebrew) it without npm, then installed npm separately, with official .sh.

That said, you mentioned that you have Linux, so that might not be the case with your issue, but this information might get you some ideas of what can be the case or help others, so posting in case :)

Good luck!