# Installation error for angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

[image: npm-error - image]

I got these errors when I run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`. What should be done to rectify these errors?

Comment: Update node/npm and run the same command again.

Comment: what is the command to update npm??

Comment: `npm update -g npm` this probably has to be run as root/administrator.

Comment: Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)