# Problems upgrading npm version

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to upgrade npm version:

`npm -v`

> 5.6.0

`sudo npm install -g npm@6`

> /home/${user}/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /home/${user}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
>
> /home/${user}/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /home/${user}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
>
> + npm@6.4.1
>
> updated 1 package in 20.723s

but still remain version of v5.6.0 after I checked with

`npm -v`

> 5.6.0

I'm using **Windows 10 (version 1803)** but I have nodejs installed on WSL running Ubuntu 18.04
Node was install following these [steps](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

**UPDATE:**

It's seems a problem with oh-my-zsh… Because I tried from bash and the versions is correct (6.4.1) and from bash when I type `zsh` I get `6.4.1` npm version. But when I start the terminal, zsh don't load the correct npm version.

I'm loading oh-my-zsh with this way

> ~/.bashrc

`bash -c zsh`

Comment: did you try to check where npm is installing your things? have you tried to close and open the terminal?

Comment: npm is on `usr/bin/npm` and yes, I tried close and open the terminal and don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with WSL and npm default install folder permissions. Trying install node again from [nodejs for ubuntu](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) and you will get npm 6.*

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then

```
npm i npm@6 -g
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: try with npm i npm@6.0.0 -g instead or npm@latest-6

Answer (score 1):

To update nodejs itself you can use nvm, like so:

see available versions and version in use:

```
`nvm ls`
```

switch to Node.js version 6.4.1:

```
`nvm use 6.4.1`
```

switch to Node.js version 9.3.0(any version, this is just an example) :

```
`nvm use 9.3`
```

switch automatically to latest Node.js version:

`nvm use node`

switch to latest LTS Node.js version:

`nvm use node --lts`

for reference, see [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/).

EDIT: Misread the question, initially, so please refer to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to update node, I just want to update npm... I don't have nvm installed

Comment: Yes, that's why I edited the answer to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions :)

Comment: Ok, let me check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use nvm to manage your node version - here is how you install it through homebrew

```
uninstall existing node
brew uninstall --force node

brew update
brew install nvm
```

save this your classpath (.bash_profile)

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

nvm install 6  (this install node version 6 stable build)
you could also do  nvm install 8 or nvm install 10 (based on the version you like to keep)

then do

```
nvm use 6
```

to use a specific node version you could also do  nvm use 10 or nvm use 8

if you like to fix this version globally on your -- add nvm use 6 to your .bash_profile