# Why I can't get NPM upgraded?

Tags: npm

Here is how I install NPM on a Linux Mint 19.

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

The NPM version I get is 3.5.2, which is not the current version. To upgrade, I try the following commands.

```
sudo npm install latest-version
```

which has a few warning messages such as "not such file or directory, open '/home/me/package.json'"
and
    sudo mpn install npm@latest -g 
which runs without any warning or error messages.

The command

```
npm -v
```

still yields 3.5.2.

What is missing?

Also, the reason of using sudo in those upgrade commands is to work around some access permission.

Comment: Permissions may be the problem. Install NVM, is much better for a user

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
which npm
```

and

```
sudo which npm
```

I suspect by running `sudo apt-get ...` you installed `npm` for your root user as opposed to your current user.

Comment: The command with sudo and without sudo yields the same path which is /usr/local/bin/npm

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `npm install -g npm@latest` or `npm install -g npm@next`

Comment: I have tried "npm install -g npm@latest". Something is installed with the command. But npm version is still the same.

Comment: try to reinstall npm.

Comment: That is what I have been doing.

Answer (score -1):

You can update NPM with: `npm install -g npm`.

[See this Q&A for more variations that might occur/needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: You should most definitely **never ever** do `sudo npm` *anything*. In general a sane development workflow never ever requires root; once it does you know you are doing something wrong. ;) If you must `npm install -g`, use the `prefix` feature of your `~/.npmrc` & `NODE_PATH` to point somewhere in your own home directory. Then you can do `npm -g install` without requiring root ever again.