# You cannot publish over the previously published versions

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I've updated my package using `npm version minor` to go from 0.4.0 to 0.5.0, and both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` reflect this.  However when I run the `npm publish` command it says:

> You cannot publish over the previously published versions: 0.4.0

Is there another place I need to update the semver in order to publish?

Answer (score 32):

This helped me:

Open Command Prompt and do the following steps.

1. `npm version <new_Version_No>`
2. `npm publish`

Comment: Is there a way to enhance my `package.json` in such a way that it always installs the latest version available on npm for a particular dependency ? something like `"black-duck-lib": "_latest_",`. I dont want to open a separate question for this small thing. plz help.

Answer (score 15):

In your package.json, there might exist a `publish` script command with content of `npm publish ...`, remove or rename the `publish` command in your scripts of package.json if there is one.

Take the following code for example, this `scripts.publish` command will again be triggered by `npm publish --access public`, running **recursively**.

```
"scripts": {
 "publish": "npm publish --access public" // this was being triggered by running `npm publish`
},
```

Comment: After spending hours trying many solutions. This answer solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

take a look at your `package.json`.
Is the `version` actually set to `0.5.0`?
If not consider setting it manually there. NPM is telling you that you already have a version `0.4.0` and it cannot publish it again. So it seems to think that it's still on `0.4.0`.

Answer (score 5):

`npm version [patch|minor|major|<version_no>]` should be done to bump up the version and then

`npm publish` for public visibility add `--access public`

This should do it.

Answer (score 4):

It happens when there is already npm module with same version.

We need to increment the npm module version and publish it again.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I was getting this error when I was trying to increase my version from `0.0.0` to `0.0.1`. However, updating from `0.0.0` to `0.1.0` worked just fine.

Comment: Do you know what the reason is? I upgrade from `0.0.9` to `0.0.10` and get a similar error: `Cannot publish over previously published version "0.0.10"`. Can I only upgrade to `0.1.0`?

Comment: @Frankie I don't know why this happens :(

Comment: Related link: [You cannot publish over previously published.. but this version has never been published](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5058)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. [Update npm version to latest.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023180/2675672)
2. `cd` into the parent folder (of the folder containing `package.json` i.e. `cd` into `A` if your files are `A/B/package.json`) and then run the command `npm publish B`.

Doing both fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned just You already publish this version! so increment that version for example if it (1.1.1) change it to(1.1.2) then  `npm i`