# how to update npm version?

Tags: node.js, npm

Currently I have npm version:5.5.1,but I want to update the version.As i'm trying to update,it is not updating.And I tried by uninstalling and reinstalling the node still i'm getting the same npm version of 5.5.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update NodeJS and NPM to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: One approach: install the update to nodejs on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

First, run PowerShell as Administrator, click Start, search for PowerShell, right-click PowerShell and select Run as Administrator.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

You will be prompted to select a version of NPM to install. Use arrow keys to move up and down and choose the version you want to update to and press Enter.

[image: see here]

If your upgrade is successful, you should see something like this.

[image: see here]