# "npm install --no-optional" results in "Missing required argument"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

`/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-optional` gives me the following error on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus):

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1098-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-optional"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/Master/npm-debug.log
```

I updated `npm` with `/usr/bin/npm install -g npm@latest` but now I get

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

What’s is wrong here?

Answer (score 16):

Your npm version is completely outdated. You are on npm v3.5.2, while npm v6.14.4 has already been released.

You need to upgrade npm to use the `--no-optional` flag. For that see:

> #### [docs.npmjs.com: Try the latest stable version of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)
>
> *You can upgrade to the latest version of npm using: `npm install -g npm@latest`*

### How to update Node.js

This is a simple solution that works for all supported operating systems, including [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows):

> After a lot of surfing and not finding a straight solution, I just
> tried going to [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) site, clicked the **DOWNLOADS** button on
> homepage and executed the installer program (MSI).
>
> Thankfully it took care of everything and with a few clicks of 'Next'
> button I got the latest Node.js version running on my Windows machine.

<sup>(Here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13770464/1429387).)</sup>

[image: Download Node.js buttons]

For [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) users, here's the official [Node.js image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

---

**PS:** To check your Node.js version, use `npm version` or `node --version`.
**PPS:** Keep an eye on the [Node.js blog - Vulnerabilities](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/), so you don't miss important security releases.

Comment: mhh... maybe because your node version is also heavily outdated. Btw. Is it really necessary to use the `--no-optional` flag?

Comment: @roy I have edited my answer as well. Please have a look. (you using node v4.2.6 and v14 is available)

Comment: A better answer for updating to latest node version:  https://askubuntu.com/a/635469/485874

Comment: Thanks so much! The better way to install is to be sure with the versions, usually when we follow some tutorial, there is really old versions.