# Installing NodeJs via snapcraft (issue)

Tags: node.js, npm, snapcraft, snap

I'm on ubuntu 22.04

I'm using nodejs that I first installed with :
`sudo apt install nodejs`

But the version I had was 12 which is very old now.
After that, I had trouble about the  node version when installing modules with NPM (warnings about deprecated packages).

So I went back to nodejs web site, and choose to reinstall via snapcraft :
`sudo snap install node --classic`

Which seemed to worked :
`node (18/stable) 18.16.0 from OpenJS Foundation (iojs✓) installed` 
But when I tried to use it, or even ask the version, I've got this error :
 `node server.js bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory`

`node -v bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory`

So... I don't what to do, as snap tells me that node is correctly installed, but doesn't seems to.

I guess I maybe confussing somewhere, but don't where...
Any idea?

Thank you.

Shall I reinstall it from binaries (which I hope not, cause I'm always scared to make mistakes this way)?
Or am I doomed to node v12 for the rest of my life.... aaaaarrrrgggh ....

Comment: Ok solved it but uninstalling via snap, reinstalling v12 via apt, then installed n via npm and update node as explained here :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-their-latest-versions?rq=2)