# How to update NodeJS and NPM to the latest version

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, node-modules, npm-update

I installed NPM for access to additional Node.js Modules.

After I installed Node.js & NPM I noticed that neither were the latest versions available.

I would like to know: How do I upgrade Node.js, NPM, and my Node.js Modules to their latest versions?

Do I need to uninstall Node.js & NPM and reinstall the latest versions?

Here is the link to what I have tried so far. This link is a section from npm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update NodeJS and NPM to their latest versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-their-latest-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Us the command `npm install -g npm`  to update npm to latest version. Use `nvm use <version>` to use a particular version of node.