# Getting 'Request is not defined' error when running a Next.js project with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, version-compatibility

I recently created a Next.js project and attempted to run it using the 'npm run dev' command, but I encountered the following error message:

['Request is not defined' Error in Next.js with Node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B1Qu.png)

After some research, I found that this error may be related to my Node.js version (16.16.0). I understand that Next.js requires Node.js 18.17 or later to run properly.

Can someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and update my Node.js version to the required one?

Comment: Please check this to update nodejs & npm https://stackoverflow.com/a/22254520/9675804